# vue-smart-route with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

Am using the package vue-smart-route to create a search functionality in my app. For the styles am using vuetify. The problem is that when i use the vuetify components it doesn't works.

Using it with vuetify component:

```
<v-text-field v-model="search" v-smart-routes="routes" class="mr-4" :label="$t('search') + '...'" hide-details append-icon="mdi-magnify" />
```

That doesn't works.

Plain html

```
<input class="mr-4" type="text" v-model="search" v-smart-routes="routes">
```

This works however i want to add the vuetify styles.

How can i make the vuetify component work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that `vue-smart-route` doesn't work with the Vuetify's `<v-text-field/>` because it probably expects an exact `<input>` HTML element, while `<v-text-field/>` creates a much more complex DOM structure. It's something like this and the `<input>` tag is deeply nested:

```
<div class="v-input v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted">
    <div class="v-input__control">
        <div class="v-input__slot">
            <div class="v-text-field__slot">
                <label for="input-1752" class="v-label v-label--active theme--light"
                    style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Label</label><input id="input-1752"
                    type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-text-field__details">
            <div class="v-messages theme--light">
                <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in this case I see 2 options: Create your own custom input similar to this one if you want to stick to these styles or branch `vue-smart-route` and make it work with this DOM structure. I hope this helps.